# Does range query TPS scale up linearly in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, consistent-hashing

Would Cassandra be suitable for this case?

1. just one single table (key/value).
2. super many rows like 10 trillions.
3. a cluster with 1000 servers
4. 50%:50% on range/list and key fetch. (TPS of range/list will increase as it grows)

I understand Cassandra will scale up well for heavy write and read queries since keys gets distributed naturally by the hash ring. And I also understand there would be a minimum effort on partitioning.

But from their white paper, my insight is that it will only scale up for queries on direct matching key. And doesn't really scale up on range/list queries since key index will be stored in a few servers just like any other keys. And also there's a chance a single range query could hit every single server in a cluster to fetch the keys. If that's the case, range query will be slower as I add more servers.

I'm wondering if my understanding is correct and also wondering if range query is something that actually scale up linearly along with keys as I add more servers.

I'm trying to find out the real challenges I'd facing in the future as it grows up like Google scale.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that with a hash partitioner Cassandra will not be able to satisfy range queries in any sort of performant way.  However Cassandra also supports a `ByteOrderedPartitioner`, which distributes keys in lexical ordering, which may be leveraged for fast range scans by partition key.

One problem with that approach is that you sacrifice automagical even distribution of keys.  This means more operational burden towards keeping your keyspace evenly distributed among nodes through manual rebalancing.  This requirement can range from being a simple annoyance to a complete blocker depending your scenario (if inserts aren't super frequent, this cost may be acceptable).

A little more information about the [ByteOrderedPartitioner](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/cluster_architecture/partitioning#byteorderedpartitioner).

Comment: Thanks Daniel for sharing your through knowledge.